# How to use NavController globally on Android JetPackCompose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I don't think my code is compact.
Do I always have to hand over the Nav Controller to the argument in this way?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ChatHome(
    navController: NavController,
    appViewModel: AppViewModel
) {
    ChatList(navController)
}


@Composable
fun ChatList(navController: NavController) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
    ) {
        items(chatItemList) { chat ->
            ChatItem(chat, navController) {}
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ChatItem(
    chat: Chat,
    navController: NavController,
    onRowClick: (Chat) -> Unit
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp)
            .clickable(onClick = {
                onRowClick(chat)
                navController.navigate("chatDetail/${chat.chatId}")
            })
    )
...
```

I wonder how to use Nav Controller globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**
If you wan't preview-able composable, you can write own wrapper:

```kotlin
// For single component
@Composable
fun ComposablePreview(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalNavigation provides rememberNavController(),
        content = content,
    )
}

// For theme
@Composable
fun AppThemePreview(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalNavigation provides rememberNavController()
    ) {
        AppTheme(darkTheme, content)
    }
}

// Usage
@Preview
@Composable
fun ComponentPreview() {
    ComposablePreview {
       // Some composable
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun ComponentPreviewWithTheme() {
    AppThemePreview {
       // Some composable
    }
}
```

**Original answer:**

You can use [CompositionLocalProvider](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal).

For example:

Define our `CompositionLocal` with `NavHostController`

```kotlin
val LocalNavigation = staticCompositionLocalOf<NavHostController> { error("Not provided") }
```

Wrap your whole project with `CompositionLocalProvider`

```kotlin
val navController = rememberNavController()
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalNavigation provides navController,
) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, ...) { ... }
}
```

And now you can call it like that:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ChatItem(
    chat: Chat,
    onRowClick: (Chat) -> Unit
) {
    val navController = LocalNavigation.current

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp)
            .clickable(onClick = {
                onRowClick(chat)
                navController.navigate("chatDetail/${chat.chatId}")
            })
    )
}
```

Comment: Along with this, you can use dagger/hilt if you are using MVVM architecture and want to manage navigation from viewmodel instead of view. You will just have to create NavManager class and assign navController in it initially. And then just inject NavManager in any viewmodel wherever you require

Comment: Please don't do this, the composable both in the question and answer is not preview-able, use state hoisting instead.

Comment: @uragiristereo can you please post an answer with state hoisting as you suggest?

Comment: @joe-pleavin you can check answer note to make preview-able composable